# Edit rejected with completely inaccurate reasoning

Tags: discussion, support

I'm dumbfounded as to how this edit actually got declined. Maybe you can enlighten me. The question was how to pass cookies in a `file_get_contents()` call - link here https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11304370 . The OP answered his own question here:

> I just used curls instead of file_get_contents and everything works
>   well with me:
>
> ```
> function request_url($method='get', $vars='', $url) {
> $ch = curl_init();
> if ($method == 'post') {
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
> }
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
> $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close($ch);
> return $buffer;
> }
> ```

So I appended this to the bottom, since I felt his answer may not help someone who's new to coding actually grasp *why* cURL works, and what this code sample is actually doing. Here's my appended edit:

> The magic happens with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.
>
> CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR tells cURL to write all internally known Cookies to
>   the specified file. In this case, 'cookies/cookies.txt'. For most
>   users, it's generally recommended to use something like
>   tempnam('/tmp', 'CURLCOOKIES') so you know for sure that you can
>   generate this file.
>
> CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE tells cURL which file to use for Cookies during
>   the cURL request. That's why we set it to the same file we just dumped
>   the Cookies to.

According to those approving/denying, I was addressing the author. Please, enlighten me, how am I addressing the author with this edit? What could possibly be addressing anyone inside this edit, other than those who could stumble upon this and wonder **why** this code works? I wanted to be clear that cookies don't *just work* simply because you're using cURL.

Here's my comment:

> Comment: A bit more explanation for anyone stumbling upon this answer
>   who do not know exactly *how* or *why* cURL works with Cookies.

Comment: How much rep did you gain or loose on this questions to date? So, does that mean you are a rep-whore??? And just because you don't like the answers doesn't make them false, nor does it mean you should start getting offensive.

Comment: I'm sorry, Nate, but this just doesn't work for suggested edits. When you don't have full edit privileges, your edits go into a queue where 3 other users have to review them and judge them as useful. There is no guarantee (in fact, there is virtually the opposite) that these 3 reviewers will be experts in the subject of whatever post you've edited. Therefore, they cannot, and you cannot expect them to, judge the content and veracity of your edit. Given all of the spam that ends up being suggested and they have to wade through, their gut instinct is to reject....

Comment: It is, unfortunately, the correct decision on their part. For the time being, you'll just have to post stuff like this as a new answer. (Please do, I would find it useful!) When you have posted enough useful answers to gain full editing privileges, then you'll able to add useful information to existing answers via edits.

Comment: Closed as this is, you still can't change the question and invalidate the answers given.

Answer (score 15):

Edits exist to improve the presentation of an existing answer, not to radically change the content of another person's answer.

You should have posted a new answer with that content, possibly using portions of the existing answer as well (cited appropriately, of course).  Editing a bunch of your own original content into someone else's answer is not what edits are for.

Comment: So let me get this right. SO would rather have a duplicate answer just for the sake of explanation? Also, providing explanation "radically" changes the content? The answer did not change at all, all that "changed" was appending explanations to the two properties that actually achieved his desired outcome.

Comment: @NateI But it *wouldn't* be a duplicate answer.  It would be an answer with a significant amount of new content, presumably of value to readers.  If you feel that you weren't changing the answer at all, then why edit it at all?  If what you provided is actually valuable, then you've radically changed the answer.  If it's adding nothing of value, then there would be no point in applying it in the first place.  If you think that answers are nothing more than the code in them, then why are you trying to edit explanations into code only answers in the first place?

Comment: So with that logic, why is there the ability to edit? If editing grammar adds nothing of value, why can anyone edit *any* post at *any* time? Furthermore, if what you're saying is true and **anything** that adds value should be a new answer, shouldn't your comments here be a new answer? Why are there comments and not just hundreds of thousands of answers per question?

Comment: @NateI but editing grammar and formatting does add value - in readability.

Comment: @NateI: Comments are for making suggestions for larger improvements to a post, or for pointing out problems that might not be fixable; you could have commented that the answer needed more of an explanation, and that would have been fine.

Comment: @Magisch Of course it adds value - that's my point. He said "If what you provided is actually valuable, then you've radically changed the answer.", prior to that he said "Edits exist to improve the presentation of an existing answer, not to radically change the content of another person's answer.". So, by his logic, **anything** that increases value should be a new answer. By this logic, I should copy and paste someone else's answer if it's poorly formatted, correct grammar/punctation/etc., and claim the answer as my own?

Comment: @NateI I never said that edits should never add value.  I said that edits shouldn't fundamentally change the content of the answer.  You're the one who said you "didn't change anything at all".  Which of course contradicts your own claim that it's adding value.  To have added value you  must have changed *something*.

Comment: All right, I purged that conversation because it was going nowhere constructive. If either of you want to continue this, I recommend heading to chat.

Comment: I'd like to point out to everyone, including you @BradLarson, the examples I've shown in my post. Single line answers evolving into muilti-paragraph answers and yet, they're fine. My edit is removed, yet these answers evolved from tiny responses to very helpful, detailed responses with a community effort.

Answer (score 9):

Well, you are writing a full explanation where there was none, instead of just improving some other posts presentation.
That's a bit too much putting your own words into that poster's mouth.

Consider just writing your own answer based on the one you used as a starting-point, and linking it to give credit. Unless, of course, you decide not to reuse that code.

Comment: Lol, that seems asinine to me. Literally just explaining what the code is doing / why that solution works is against the rules? The content didn't change at all, the only thing that changed was an explanation was added.

Comment: @NateI Adding such an explanation isn't against, the rules, you just didn't do it in the proper way.  Had you posted that content as a new answer, it would have been fine.

Comment: @Servy Would have been fine in what context? In the context that no one even reads my answer (and it probably gets downvoted)? I'm not posting a duplicate answer and getting downvoted simply to satisfy the rep-whores. I'll just mentor the devs who are directly under me and let SO continue to be run into the ground by becoming a popularity contest.

Comment: @NateI "_the only thing that changed was an explanation was added_" exactly.  That wasn't part of the original answer in any way.  So you are adding _completely new content_.  That is not great for edits, and it is good enough to be an answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu So why are there edits? Please explain to me if it's better to have 10 answers with slightly varying content to form one legitimate answer, why is there the ability to edit? Why can't a person pick 5 best answers if "best practice" is to just answer no matter how little you have to offer on the scenario with the general idea that "if you do *anything* to alter an answer in *any* way, you should just post a new answer"? Finally, if this is the case, why is there not a reason for this in the approval/denial process? Why doesn't it say "content change was too dramatic"?

Comment: @NateI If you want to know why edits exist, and how you're supposed to use them, then I suggest you read through the help center's section on editing.  You should have done that before posting a meta question claiming that an edit was improperly rejected.  Understanding the rules of ran appropriate edit is something you should have actually looked up before claiming that your edit didn't violate any of them.

Comment: @NateI: Well, yes, being pedantic, they should have chosen "*clearly conflicts with author's intent*  
This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner. " Didn't seem that important though.

Comment: @Deduplicator How does it conflict with the author's intent?

Comment: @NateI He didn't want to explain, and anyway would have a completely different explanation?

Comment: @Deduplicator If he didn't want anyone to know the solution, why post an answer at all? His intent was to help people by showing the solution that helped him. Otherwise, he would not have posted the answer. *That* intent doesn't not stray from my intent, which was to further help those stumbling upon the answer. That **should be** everyone's intent on SO - to help others. However, much like is made very clear here, most people just want to get into a dick measuring contest. The edit I made neither violated rules or contradicted his post in any way - it would have simply helped others.

Comment: If there was no paper trail, I could see being so uptight about an edit like this. However, when absolutely everyone can see the edit I made, it's not necessarily *putting words in his mouth*, it's building upon something to make a good answer a great one. I don't think what I put would make his answer great, I'm just making the point that it would benefit a **lot** more to have a community-oriented mindset instead of a "post a separate answer for free rep" mentality.

Comment: @NateI: Then make a discussion on meta and try to convince people that allowing everyone to add gobs of their own original content to non-CW posts is a good idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's quite out of context. Adding explanation to two properties is hardly "adding gobs of my own original content". Even if it were in context, it's not against the rules to do what I did. Had I posted what I did as a comment to his answer, a rep-whore would have been able to edit the post to include the elaboration no problem. I myself would have had a much greater likelihood of having it put in place with that process as well.

Comment: The examples I've provided have essentially proven this answer wrong as a whole.

Comment: No, they don't, and you don't even link to the specific edit you mean, I had to guess. Also, a few mis-applications of the rules wouldn't invalidate them. Anyway, I meant you should post a new question for that.

Comment: @Deduplicator They don't? So you mean to tell me you know the rules better than anyone else? Clearly more people have seen the posts I've pointed out than most other posts on SO. You don't think those who write the rules have seen them? Are you telling me those posts, which are now incredibly helpful and in-depth *should* be rolled back to a less informative state simply because you say so?

Answer (score 3):

I posted the contents of the edit as a new CW answer, with attribution and left a comment under the original answer for future readers.

The other answerers here have already explained why the edit was rejected.

> "I just feel that the only power I have is setting a good example." ~ Geri Halliwell